# How can I require a captcha to load a page?

Tags: php, captcha

I would like a simple PHP captcha script that would require the user so solve a captcha to load the website page. Preferably a captcha that doesn't need a third party such as reCAPTCHA, all done locally.

EDIT: Ended up making a text box to enter the link you would like to protect and it would automatically generate a captcha protected link, and a deletion link to delete the protected link.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the example here:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-own-captcha-and-contact-form-in-php--net-5362

I would also recommend using the timer on your page since bots are becoming better at passing capchas. By timer, I mean time between landing on the page and creating an account/submitting the form.

Comment: This is more for specifically protecting a form, which I tend to see everywhere. I need to protect the webpage content itself. I've tried putting pieces together from captchas like this before to build it myself, but can't ever get it working perfectly.

Comment: What errors/issues are you exactly having when trying to put it together?

Comment: Mainly had issues making sure there was no way to bypass the captcha to see the content. I think I managed to make a good solution that works well. If you know a good script that can help with auto protecting certain links with the captcha that would be very useful. Maybe like a text-box where you input the URL and it generates a captcha protected link. Currently I must manually make each one.

Comment: requiring captcha before page loading is easy just check if `$_SESSION and cookie` generated by captcha when user input matched the captcha exist .. else keep showing the captcha   ... also you can also create self expiring cookie when that cookie is expire then delete the `$_SESSION` and not show the page content which act like a timer also providing snippet code on what actually trying to achievce would be helpful

Comment: After hours of work I managed to make a site that lets you enter a URL and automatically generate a captcha protected URL. Proud of myself. :D

No third parties. No JavaScript required.

Answer (score 0):

This is VERY simple.  Usually no one is going to put any effort to bypass the captcha unless you have something worth while aka $$$$.

Just post an image with a question. Like What is 345 x 100,000 + 957?
The have an small form with a `<input>` for them to answer.

You could have any number of images and answers.

```
$captcha[] = array($answer,$image);
$captcha[] = array($answer,$image);
$captcha[] = array($answer,$image);
```

Then

```
 $cnt = count($captcha) - 1;
 $rec = rand(0,$cnt);
 $answer= captcha[$rec][0];
 $image = captcha[$rec][1];
 echo '<img scr="$image"/>';
 echo '<form action="$url" method="post">';
 echo '<input type = "text" name="answer" /></form>';
 $id = intval(str_replace('.','',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
 file_put_contents("$id.txt",$answer);
```

The in the $url page:

```
 $id = intval(str_replace('.','',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
 $answer = intval(file_get_contents("$id.txt"));
 unlink("$id.txt");
 $pass = false;
 if $answer == intval($_POST['answer']){$pass = true;}
```